# How to put the control name before action name in routes on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-routes

**handy_network_tools** is my controller

**search_camera** is my action in the controller

I want to write the routes file in nested way.

```
  resources :handy_network_tools do
    collection do
      get :search_camera
    end
  end
```

I prefer **handy_network_tools_search_camera** rather than **search_camera_handy_network_tools**

Any ideas ?

```
search_camera_handy_network_tools GET    /handy_network_tools/search_camera(.:format)          handy_network_tools#search_camera
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route helpers are automatically defined from child to parent. If you want to change the name of the route method, you can set it explicitly using `as`.

```
resources :handy_network_tools do
  collection do
    get :search_camera, as: :handy_network_tools_search_camera
  end
end
```